# mouseMoveTracking in QtGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I want to track mouse in my main window.
I have enabled the moustracking in the QGraphicsView
here is the constructor for GraphicsView subclass, the rest is the default behavior.

```
GraphicsView::GraphicsView(QWidget* parent): QGraphicsView(parent)
{

  setMouseTracking(true);

  setDragMode(RubberBandDrag);
  setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing|  QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
  setMinimumSize(600, 400);

}
```

here is my GraphicsScene MouseMove method:

```
void GraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
  if (myMode == InsertLine && line != nullptr) {
      QLineF newLine(line->line().p1(), mouseEvent->scenePos());
      line->setLine(newLine);
  } else if (myMode == Select) {
      QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
  }
  QPointF point = mouseEvent->pos();
  //point = this->mapToScene(point);
  qDebug() << point.x() << " " << point.y() << " ";
  mouseMoved(point);
  QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
}
```

I get zero and zero for x and y  position. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you review the docs of [`pos()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html#pos) method of QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent:

> Returns the mouse cursor position in item coordinates.

That is, those coordinates are relative to a QGraphicsItem, but in this case there are no coordinates and consequently it has no meaning (it would only have it if the mouseMoveEvent would belong to a QGraphicsItem). In this case you must use the [`scenePos()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html#scenePos) method

```cpp
void GraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
  // ...
  QPointF point = mouseEvent->scenePos();
  qDebug() << point.x() << " " << point.y() << " ";
  // ...
  QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
}
```